# Why can I run a playbook successfully as root but NOT as the user who owns the playbook?

Tags: ansible, firewalld

I am trying to run a playbook and part of the playbooks job is to add a firewall port. What is the best way to do this? I get this error with the `lineinfile` module:

```
- name: Ensure specific port configuration in firewalld`
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:`
    path: /etc/firewalld/zones/drop.xml
    insertbefore: '^<accept/>'
    line: '<port port= "6556" protocol="tcp"/>'
    backrefs: yes
    state: present
    become: yes`
```

Things I tried: I tried using ansible.posix.firewalld but that did not work due to python versions.

Comment: By default, a non-root user would not have access to modify `/etc/firewalld/zones/drop.xml`.  So I would expect this playbook to only work when run by `root` or by using `sudo` or configuring ansible to utilize it's `become` functionality.  Even using `ansible.posix.firewalld` would require `root` or `sudo` to operate.

Comment: Your `become` parameter is indented too far. It should line up with the module name.

Answer (score -1):

Try:
`sudo -u [user] ansible-playbook [playbook name] --ask-become-pass`

*With sudo permissions, run ansible playbook as [user] and ask for the become pass for that user.*

The --ask flag can be permanently affixed to the ansible.cfg with a some other options like become_password_file=/path/to/file.

As Graceful mentioned, the owner of the playbook may not have the correct permissions to modify the firewalld config. Best practice is just to run your firewall-cmd with sudo instead of granting a specific user access.

Comment: This will probably not work if the target machine is remote. Using `sudo` to invoke root to run ansible-playbook does not guarantee the remote machine will accept a connection by root. Very poor practice. Ansible has `become` functionality to use sudo or other tools to invoke different users and privileges.